# How to run a method in App1 from App2 in iOS?

Tags: ios8

I have two iOS applications, App1 and App2. I need to log out from App2 and then it will fire logout automatically for App1.

Is this possible for iOS?

Comment: Do you maintain/own both of these apps?

Answer (score 0):

You should register custom url scheme in the app, which you want to call from another app. See http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html. However I do not know, whether your idea with autologout from another app will be approved by Apple. Use case itself sounds absurd.